# Arduino disassemble sketch from flash

Tags: arduino, reverse-engineering

I have an Arduino device witch has a sketch loaded on it. My question is can I read the sketch from the memory (hex file) and the dissansamble it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I would recommend you use ReAVR:
http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?func=viewItem&item_id=272&module=Freaks%20Tools

To get the HEX file, use an in system programmer like the AVR ISP MKII and use AVR Studio to read the hex directly.

Comment: I understand that using ReAVR I can convert the code back to asm code from hex but how to download the sketch from the arduino...?

Comment: You must use an in-system programmer such as the AVR ISP MKII to read the hex file.